# Order by timestamp works incorrectly

Tags: mysql, sql

From the following table, I'm trying to select `distinct(id)` and `order` them by the `timestamp desc`. But I don't seem to be getting correct results.

```
"id"    "head"  "type"  "updated"   "userId"    "addedDate"
"1"     "2"     "0"     "1"         "1"         "2013-11-23 21:09:23"
"1"     "2"     "1"     "1"         "1"         "2013-11-23 21:09:40"
"2"     "2"     "0"     "1"         "1"         "2013-11-23 21:09:44"
"2"     "2"     "1"     "0"         "1"         "2013-11-23 21:09:47"
```

**My Query**

```
select distinct(id) as id, addedDate from test 
where userId = 1 group by id order by addedDate desc;
```

**Current results**

```
"id"    "addedDate"
"2"     "2013-11-23 21:09:44"
"1"     "2013-11-23 21:09:23" // This is wrong. 
                 //It should have been the one with 2013-11-23 21:09:40
```

**Desired Results**

```
"id"    "addedDate"
"2"     "2013-11-23 21:09:47" //The one that was added last
"1"     "2013-11-23 21:09:40" //The one that was added last
```

Comment: `select id, MAX(addedDate) AS max_addedDate from test where userId = 1 group by id order by max_addedDate desc;`

Comment: @ypercube Your answer worked well.

Comment: @ypercube If I don't want to select max(addedDate) in the select, but still wanted them ordered by max(addedDate) how is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your query uses `GROUP BY` in a very wrong way. You want to find the maximum `addedDate` for every `id`:

```
SELECT id, MAX(addedDate) AS max_addedDate 
FROM test 
WHERE userId = 1 
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY max_addedDate DESC ;
```

Even if you don't want to show the max date in the `SELECT` list, you can still use it in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT id
FROM test 
WHERE userId = 1 
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY MAX(addedDate) DESC ;
```

---

If you have different requirements (as you mention in the comments) and you also want to show more columns from the table (but still for rows with the max date per id), you can use the above query with a join:

```
SELECT t.id, t.addedDate, t.type           -- whatever columns you want from `t`
FROM test AS t
  JOIN
    ( SELECT id, MAX(addedDate) AS addedDate 
      FROM test 
      WHERE userId = 1 
        AND head = 2
      GROUP BY id 
    ) AS m
    ON  m.id = t.id
    AND m.addedDate = t.addedDate
WHERE t.userId = 1 
  AND t.head = 2
ORDER BY t.addedDate DESC ;
```

Comment: You second one does not order by addedDate desc. Note: I added a column next to id in the select. Could this be causing the problem?

Comment: The ordering is done correctly. The other column is showing semi-random results.

Comment: Any chance we can get correct results without using max() in the select? Because I use PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR to put values into an array later in php.

Comment: Did it like this Ugh! What you think? `select a, b from(
SELECT id a, type b, MAX(addedDate) FROM test WHERE userId=1 AND head=2 Group By id
)c;`

Answer (score -1):

Try to add the clause:

```
HAVING MAX(addedDate)
```

Answer (score -1):

try doing it like this:

> SELECT DISTINCT id FROM test ORDER BY order by convert(datetime, addedDate, 103) DESC;

The convert() will convert the date into a varchar which will easily be determined.